# How to run custom docker image from k3s(ARGO)

Tags: kubernetes, argo

I have ARGO in k3s and I want to start custom docker image from it.
I have uploaded image to k3s but when I am trying to run it I am getting

`k3s-master k3s[1102]: E0330 17:49:39.188518 1102 pod_workers.go:190] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"main\" with ImagePullBackOff: \"Back-off pulling image \\\"simulator:latest\\\"\"" pod="argo/simulator" podUID=cc93d538-f26b-4075-a367-19ed0557da1f`

Saw that path should be different from `simulator:latest`
something like that `xxx/xxx/xxx/simulator:latest`
and imagePullPolicy should be `"Never"`

Comment: Where did you see what the path for simulator should be different?  What is simulator?

Comment: simulator is docker image, I put it docker-registry 
- name: whalesay
      container:
        image: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/m-simulator:latest'

evrything works, thanks